# How to center text in my style?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my text "EXAMPLE". I have the text-align center in my span tag, but it's not centering. I only want "Example" center and not the other text.

check out my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/dx5fe6x5/

HTML

```
<p class="textbox">
<span style="text-align:center; color:#2251a4; font-weight:bold;letter-spacing: 10px;">EXAMPLE</span><br><br> The powers of the Company shall be exercised by or under the authority of, and the business and affairs of the Company shall be managed under the direction of, one or more managers. The Manager(s) shall be: Jane Doe, John Doe and Yogi Berra.</p>
```

CSS

```
.textbox {
padding: 8px 12px;
color: #555555;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
border: #e2e3e4 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:block;` to the spans styles:

```css
.textbox {
    padding: 8px 12px;
color: #555555;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
border: #e2e3e4 2px solid;
}
.title{
    text-align:center;
    color:#2251a4; 
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    display:block;
        
}
```

```html
<p class="textbox">
    <span class="title">EXAMPLE</span>
  he powers of the Company shall be exercised by or under the authority of, and the business and affairs of the Company shall be managed under the direction of, one or more managers. The Manager(s) shall be: Jane Doe, John Doe and Yogi Berra.
</p>
```

I would highly recommend you do not use inline styles, and only use `<br>`'s where they are supposed to be used, **not** for structure!
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hjz56qor/)

Answer (score 0):

The span tag is an inline tag - meaning inherently, you cannot center it.

However, if you change its display to "block", you can adjust the left and right margins to auto, you can - like so:

```
.textbox>span{
display:block;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
```

}

Using a ">" will only target "spans" directly following a .textbox class.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dx5fe6x5/5/